Excel round to multiple of 100 using ceiling 100 if the hundredths is >800
I'm looking to increase the number by 25%, but I also need to round up to the nearest multiple of 100, but only if the hundredth is ">800." If the hundredth is "<800," round to the nearest multiple of 10.
So, for example:
    6325 = 6330
    7889 = 7900
    7916 = 7920
    7850 = 7900


why is the third one 7920 and not 8000?

If you insist on using CEILING, try =CEILING(A1,IF(MOD(A1,1000)>800,100,10)).

Use:
=ROUNDUP(A1,IF(MOD(A1,1000)>800,-2,-1))



Or more succinct:
=ROUNDUP(A1,-1-(MOD(A1,1000)>800))



@Scott-Carner This is a nice solution, I appreciate it. Could you please clarify how MOD is working to evaluate the number at its hundredth?

@mjl Mod is giving the remainder of the variable and the divisor (1000), so for the first example 6325 / 1000 gives a remainder of 325. This is then validated against >800, and since 325>800 it results in false so it is rounded up by the value of -1 (the tens digit). If it were true it would round up by -2 (the hundred digit).

Love the last logic -1-(TRUE/FALSE) for roundup.
